# cannot change hover color for link inside a div

Tags: css

I try to add a custom color to a link inside a div but its not working, the color does not change. Why is that?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Untitled</title>
  <style>
      .navigation-div a {
        display: block;
        font-size: 18px;
        color: #14133b !important;
        line-height: 1;
        margin-bottom: 26px;
    }

    .navigation-div a:hover {
        color: #CEA941 !important;
    }

    .navigation-div a:visited {
        color: #14133b !important;
    }
    .navigation-div a:link {
        color: #14133b !important;
    }
    .navigation-div a:visited {
        color: #14133b !important;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
<table class="table" style="border-bottom: 0px solid black;">
<tbody><tr>
<td valign="top"></td>
<td valign="top">header 1</td>
<td valign="top">header 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top"></td>
<td><div class="navigation-div">
<a href="#"> Motor  </a></div>
</td>
<td><div class="navigation-div">
<a href="#">12345 </a></div>
</td>
</tr>

</tbody></table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So since you're using a table you have to go through each element like this :

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Untitled</title>
  <style>
    /* a{
      color: black;
    }
    a:hover{
      color: reds;
    } */
table> tbody > tr>td>.navigation-div >a:hover{
 color: red;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<table class="table" style="border-bottom: 0px solid black;">
<tbody>
 <tr>
      <td valign="top"></td>
      <td valign="top">header 1</td>
      <td valign="top">header 2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
      <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td valign="top"></td>
      <td><div class="navigation-div">
      <a href="#"> Motor  </a></div>
     </td>
     <td><div class="navigation-div">
     <a href="#">12345 </a></div>
     </td>
   </tr>

</tbody></table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the important keyword from your style in .navigation-div a, a: link and a:visited (you dont need the important keyword anywhere):

```
    .navigation-div a {
            display: block;
            font-size: 18px;
            color: #14133b;
            line-height: 1;
            margin-bottom: 26px; 
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting your hover styles with the `:link` selector a couple of lines later. In general, try and avoid overusing `!important` - there's no need for it in this situation. Try this:

```css
.navigation-div a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #14133b;
  line-height: 1;
  margin-bottom: 26px;
}

.navigation-div a:hover {
  color: #CEA941;
}

.navigation-div a:visited {
  color: #14133b;
}
```

```html
<table class="table" style="border-bottom: 0px solid black;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top"></td>
      <td valign="top">header 1</td>
      <td valign="top">header 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top"></td>
      <td>
        <div class="navigation-div">
          <a href="#"> Motor  </a></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="navigation-div">
          <a href="#">12345 </a></div>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

If you *really* need to keep the `!important` rules, you can just move your `:hover` style underneath the `:link`

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Untitled</title>
  <style>
      .navigation-div a {
        display: block;
        font-size: 18px;
        color: #14133b !important;
        line-height: 1;
        margin-bottom: 26px;
    }

    td .navigation-div a:hover {
        color: #CEA941 !important;
    }

    .navigation-div a:visited {
        color: #14133b !important;
    }
    .navigation-div a:link {
        color: #14133b !important;
    }
    .navigation-div a:visited {
        color: #14133b !important;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
<table class="table" style="border-bottom: 0px solid black;">
<tbody><tr>
<td valign="top"></td>
<td valign="top">header 1</td>
<td valign="top">header 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top"></td>
<td><div class="navigation-div">
<a href="#"> Motor  </a></div>
</td>
<td><div class="navigation-div">
<a href="#">12345 </a></div>
</td>
</tr>

</tbody></table>
</body>

</html>
```

use this code . it's work .

Answer (score 0):

All those `!important` "collide" with each other; simply maintaining the one assigned to the `navigation-div a:hover` should be enough. Try not overuse the `!important` keyword, usually it's not the best thing to do.

In your code, the `color` property of `navigation-div a:hover` was overwritten multiple times by the other selectors. The only one that should prevail on the others, for your intended behavior, is the `hover` one, in fact you could also omit the other selectors and so the use of `!important`.

```css
.navigation-div a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #14133b;
  line-height: 1;
  margin-bottom: 26px;
}

.navigation-div a:hover {
  color: #cea941;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Untitled</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table class="table" style="border-bottom: 0px solid black">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top"></td>
        <td valign="top">header 1</td>
        <td valign="top">header 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top"></td>
        <td>
          <div class="navigation-div">
            <a href="#"> Motor </a>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="navigation-div">
            <a href="#">12345 </a>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```